# no Istio pods in namespace "istio-system"

Tags: istio

I have installed istioctl/1.4.8, istioctl is not able to talk to my cluster, using command (istioctl version -c platform)

```
#kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

# kubectl get pods -A  | grep -i istio | grep pilot
istio-platform      istio-pilot-7c5adrgcd89-wt9k                       2/2     Running       4          1d

#istioctl version
2020-06-14T11:26:13.636825Z warn    will use `--remote=false` to retrieve version info due to `no Istio pods in namespace "istio-system"`
1.4.8

# istioctl version -c istio-platform
2020-06-14T11:27:59.121013Z warn    will use `--remote=false` to retrieve version info due to `no Istio pods in namespace "istio-system"`
1.4.8
```

istio is running in namespace : istio-platform

What could be the issue here, any hints ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide the Istio namespace if its not in `istio-system`:

```
istioctl version -i istio-platform
```

cf. https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/

Comment: Thank you for quick answer !!